# ODE $y'+ x\sin( 2y) = x e^{-x^2} \cos^2 (y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE:

$$y'+ x\sin (2y) = x e^{-x^2} \cos^2 (y)$$

I'm stuck trying to get it into a linear form. I've tried $\sin (2y) = \sin y \cos y $ and then dividing the ODE by $( \cos  y ) ^{-1} $. This got me to nothing so I tried dividing by $( \sin y )^{-2} $ instead. I got stuck as well. I think I need to make a substitution but I don't know which one.

Thanks.

Comment: Rewrite the DE as:
$(e^{x^2} \tan  (y))'=x$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

$$y'+x\sin(2y)=xe^{-x^2}\cos^2y\\\implies\sec^2y\  y' + 2x\tan y=xe^{-x^2}\ , \text{\{let $\tan y =t\implies \sec^2 y \ y'= t'$\}}\\\implies t' +2xt =xe^{-x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y'+ x\sin( 2y) = x e^{-x^2} \cos^2 (y)$$
Multiply by $2x'$ and substitute $u=x^2$:
$$2+ 2xx'\sin( 2y) = 2xx' e^{-x^2} \cos^2 (y)$$
$$2+ u'\sin( 2y) = -( e^{-u})' \cos^2 (y)$$
$$2(\tan y)'+ 2u'\tan( y) = -( e^{-u})' $$
Multiply by $e^u$:
$$2(e^u\tan y)' = -e^u( e^{-u})' $$
$$2d(e^u\tan y) = -e^ud( e^{-u}) $$
Integrate.
$$\boxed {2e^{x^2}\tan y -x^2=C} $$

---

Note that you can also rewrite the DE as:
$$(e^{x^2} \tan  (y))'=x$$
And integrate.